# AGOL: Reduce precision in hosted feature layer view

Tags: arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer, precision-scale

I’d like to share an AGOL hosted feature layer **view** with a sister organization, but I want the locations of my records to be rounded to 3 decimal degrees accuracy in the view layer, so that exact locations are obscured.

What is the best way to accomplish this? The feature layer is a feature class regularly updated with records from Survey123. The best I could come up with (without downloading, manipulating, and re-uploading) was to:

- Create a new dummy points layer with locations only present at the “rounded” lat and long locations, provide a unique ID per point
- Join this to my survey123 layer's existing data to add dummy point ID to each existing record
- Alter survey form to pull point ID from points layer, so each new record has an associated record from the dummy points layer (using directions [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformformulas.htm) and the `pulldata("@layer")` function to autofill point ID)
- Create a view layer that joins the survey123 layer with dummy points layer and share that.

This seems complex – is there another option? I’ve searched for about an hour but perhaps this isn’t a common request or I’m using incorrect search terms. Currently, my workflow is to pull the data into R, truncate the lats and longs, export to fGDB, and overwrite a shared web layer in ArcGIS Pro but this is pretty clunky.

This post might help: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/displaying-data-from-a-second-geopoint-question-on/td-p/1007503

Comment: If you're using Survey123 Connect, you could create a new hidden repeat, that copies the attributes desired, and also calculates the geometry using rounded coordinate values of the original geometry.  Then, create a view of the layer made from the hidden repeats to be shared with the other organization.  This does create two separate datasets, but it's entirely managed by the Survey123 logic.  You may have to migrate your existing data to a newly created hosted feature layer since this significantly changes your hosted schema.

Comment: @evv_gis this sounds super easy and sneaky! How would I create a view layer from the hidden repeats - can you point me to documentation?

Comment: When you [create hosted layer views](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/create-hosted-views.htm), you can select/deselect layers.  So if your modified schema includes the original (parent) layer, and the hidden (child) layer, you can simply select the hidden layer for the view.  I've done something similar with Survey123 to collect data, and also populate another table rather than developing an ETL to keep two different schemas updated.

Comment: I'll give this a try on a test dataset and report back if I have questions. Thanks!

Comment: It seems expression arcpy.Point(news,newy) on Shape field is simplest way to move points

Comment: @evv_gis, I got this to work on a test survey where I created the survey from scratch. But in reality, I already have the data in an existing fGDB (but not the copied information yet). So I'll have to figure out how/if it is possible to migrate my existing data.

Comment: Here is a guide I made in the ESRI community board for how to migrate existing data to the parent and child layers: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/best-way-to-fill-survey123-with-parent-and-child/m-p/1356823#M53231